# How can I change the background to a shape I already made, according to a string (I wish to change the status Bckgrnd)

Tags: android

MAINSCREEN

```
imports;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    // Declare Variables
        ListView list;
        TextView text;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        EditText editsearch;
        String[] title;
        String[] date;
        String[] status;
        ArrayList<ListCourse> arraylist = new ArrayList<ListCourse>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        date = new String[] { "11/01/2011", "10/05/2006", "12/07/2002", "05/04/2011", "01/08/2012",
                              "09/12/2017", "22/06/2024", "31/01/2000", "10/10/2156", "10/02/2006" };

        title = new String[] { "Programação", "Matemática", "Logística",
                "Mobile", "Sistemas Operativos", "iOS", "Android", "Windows",
                "Hardware", "Formação" };

        status = new String[] { " ongoing ", " ongoing ",
                " ongoing ", " standby ", " ongoing ", " ongoing ",
                " ongoing ", " ongoing ", " finished ", " ongoing " };

        // Locate the ListView in listview_main.xml

        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length; i++) 
        {
            ListCourse wp = new ListCourse(date[i], title[i],
                    status[i]);
            // Binds all strings into an array
            arraylist.add(wp);
        }

                // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

       return rootView;
    }
}
```

Do I need to paste my adapter too? The id of the TextView in the .xml layout is status.
My idea is to change the background to yellow if standy, red to finish and green to ongoing. I have a shape_"color".xml for each one.

ADAPTER

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ListCourse> coursepopulatelist = null;
    private ArrayList<ListCourse> arraylist;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<ListCourse> coursepopulatelist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.coursepopulatelist = coursepopulatelist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ListCourse>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(coursepopulatelist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        TextView date;
        TextView status;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return coursepopulatelist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ListCourse getItem(int position) {
        return coursepopulatelist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        // Set the results into TextViews
        holder.title.setText(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.date.setText(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getDate());
        holder.status.setText(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getStatus());

        // Listen for ListView Item Click
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass all data rank
                intent.putExtra("title",(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getTitle()));
                // Pass all data country
                intent.putExtra("date",(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getDate()));
                // Pass all data population
                intent.putExtra("status",(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getStatus()));
                // Pass all data flag
                // Start SingleItemView Class
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // Filter Class
    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        coursepopulatelist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            coursepopulatelist.addAll(arraylist);
        } 
        else 
        {
            for (ListCourse wp : arraylist) 
            {
                if (wp.getDate().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) 
                {
                    coursepopulatelist.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And this is my `shape.xml`, example red.

shape

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:padding="10dp" android:shape="rectangle"

<solid android:color="#c50504" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dip"
    android:color="#c50504" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" />
```

Comment: I forgot to mention its according to the status string.

Comment: do you know how to the background, but not how to determine which background to use?  What actual thing is the issue?

Comment: do paste the adapter as well

Comment: Pasted Adapter and Shape. @vipulmittal

Comment: The issue is to set the shape to the listview item where the corresponding string is. @NathanielWaggoner

Comment: set the same shape to your list item just change the color inside getView wrt status. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the same shape to your list item just change the color inside `getView` wrt status.
try changing your getView to:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.status = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    // Set the results into TextViews
    holder.title.setText(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.date.setText(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getDate());
    holder.status.setText(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getStatus());
    //<<----------See the code below-------------------
    int color = Color.RED;
    String s=coursepopulatelist.get(position).getStatus();
    if (s.trim().equals("ongoing")) {
        color = Color.GREEN;
    } else if (s.trim().equals("standby")) {
        color = Color.YELLOW;
    } else if (s.trim().equals("finished")) {
        color = Color.RED;
    }

    GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) holder.status.getBackground();
    gd.setColor(color);

    // Listen for ListView Item Click
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SingleItemView.class);
            // Pass all data rank
            intent.putExtra("title",(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getTitle()));
            // Pass all data country
            intent.putExtra("date",(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getDate()));
            // Pass all data population
            intent.putExtra("status",(coursepopulatelist.get(position).getStatus()));
            // Pass all data flag
            // Start SingleItemView Class
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

Comment: String s=coursepopulatelist.get(position).getStatus();
     if (s.trim().equals("ongoing")) {
      holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_green);
     } else if (s.trim().equals("standby")) {
      holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_yellow);
     } else if (s.trim().equals("finished")) {
      holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_red);
     }

Comment: Thank you. This took me a while :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this, depending on how much memory you have available, etc. It seems like all you really want to do is to change the background color. Given that, I would do the following:

1. Create a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) that contains the colors you want indexed by the strings.
2. It seems you want to change the background of the individual item based on the string that it contains. In that case, you'll want to check the value of each string inside the view, and set the color based off of what it ends up with in the HashMap.

For instance.

```
static HashMap<String, Integer> colorMap=null;

//This should be run from the constructor
public populateMap () {
    if (colorMap==null) {
        colorMap=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        colorMap.add("finish",0xffff0000);
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    String text; //Put in your text value here
    TextView tv; // This is your view, I'm assuming a TextView
    tv.setText(text);
    if (colorMap.containsKey(text)) {
        tv.setBackgroundColor(colorMap.get(text));
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems nice but I already have an oval xml shape to use in the background, I would prefer to have that cornered shape. I made 3 of them for each color.

Comment: Then use setDrawable instead, same principal.